# Print progress in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a "main" procedure that calls others procedures inside a loop. I'd like to get messages displayed, showing when the procedure starting and when it completed, like so:

```sql
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOOP 1 STARTED');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCEDURE 1 STARTED'); 
PROCEDURE_1(x, y);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCEDURE 1 COMPLETED');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCEDURE 2 STARTED');  
PROCEDURE_2(x, y); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCEDURE 2 COMPLETED');  
                   .
                   .
                   .
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOOP 2 STARTED');
```

The problem is that doing this, the messages are only displayed after all the procedure have been completed. Is there a way to get these messages to be displayed "live"? Is there anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

`dbms_output` just writes to a memory buffer that the client application can access after the call completes.  So the client application can't display the output until after the execution completes.

The simplest approach would generally be to write data to a log table using an autonomous transaction and then have a separate session that queries the log table to display progress.  You could build an alternative solution with `dbms_mail` since that isn't transactional or `utl_http` to make a HTTP call to refresh a web page with the current status or the `dbms_alert` or `dbms_aq` package to send messages to other components in the system.  But that would generally require more plumbing to get set up.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a built-in PL/SQL logging package, but the closest thing to an industry standard is Tyler Muth's open source library `logger` which is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger).